# How to check conditions of two parameters in my case

Tags: swift

Say I have a closure with two optional parameters:

```
(data: MyData?, error: Error?) in 
  // I want to safely unwrap data & make sure error is nil
  if let data = data, let error== nil {
  }
```

The `if` condition above gives me error: `Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer.`

I understand I might have used wrong syntax with the `let error==nil` part. But, what is the correct way to do the condition check ?

Comment: In almost all cases it's sufficient to check only one parameter. For example in the completion handler of `NSURLSessionDataTask` `error` is `nil` if `data` is valid and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Swift 3 just drop `let` before `error`

```
if let data = data, error == nil {
    // do stuff
}
```

Before Swift 3 the syntax was a little different

```
if let data = data where error == nil {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it can be a good idea  to use guard :

```
 (data: MyData?, error: Error?) in 
  // I want to safely unwrap data & make sure error is nil
  guard let data = data, error == nil else {
    return 
  }
  // code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `if case` with pattern matching:

```
if case let (data?, nil) = (data, error) {
    // ...
}
```

Here `data?` is the "optional pattern" and a shortcut for `.some(data)`.